# AWS SQS message to decouple backend operations? Trigger api via SQS message possible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, amazon-sqs

I am planning to use SQS to decouple the backend operations for file processing.
I essentially have a file processing api which runs on AWS ECS. My planned architecture is as follows:

A lambda function gets the request and it creates an SQS message. **Is it possible for the SQS message to then trigger the backend process by triggering/calling the file processing api?**

**Or should i create a windows service that checks for new SQS messages** in the queue and trigger the backend processes?

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to set up a lambda to get the request and create an SQS message. You can create an API Gateway service proxy to directly map a request to an SQS queue. This plugin https://github.com/horike37/serverless-apigateway-service-proxy makes it super simple.
2. You can follow the process here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html to trigger an ECS task based on a CloudWatch event

Answer (score 1):

SQS is a poll/pull-based service, so it can't automatically trigger another event, whereas SNS is a push-based subscription service which will automatically push updates to its topics to any of its subscribers.

You have (at least) a couple of options, you could either use the lambda to post to an SNS topic, which would then be subscribed to by the file processing API, or you create a service, as you suggest, that polls the SQS queue (eg every minute, hour day etc) and handles the queued message(s) and then removes them from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the SQS message to then trigger the backend process
>   by triggering/calling the file processing API

First thing, SQS not designed to trigger or call APIs it's for messaging exchange purpose, You should better explore SNS for this purpose, SNS is capable to publish message to `HTTP endpoint`.

[image]

Second thing, This approach will kill the purpose of SQS.

[image]

So in the first case, your Lambda function will [send message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-send-message.html) to SQS 
and the backend API server will listen for the messages in the SQS and will execute an action based on SQS message body.

So the best approach is the backend API server should fire the action based on SQS message instead of introducing the third layer which will call backend API.

If your backend server is down for some reason and third service (which call backend API) how you will handle these cases? So better to process by backend itself.

**For the second approach**, I will suggest using [SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/), In this case, you lambda function will publish the message to SNS topic and backend API server SQS will subscribe for this SNS topic.

[image]

In this diagram, your Lamda will publish to the topic and the backend API will consume the message and perform operations which you exposed as an API call.